# Mapreduce Stuck in running : INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1506081922448_0004

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

```
[hadoop@master mapreduce]$ hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.4.jar wordcount /wordcount/input/ /wordcount/output


17/09/22 20:33:50 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/09/22 20:33:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0
17/09/22 20:33:50 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0
17/09/22 20:33:51 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1506081922448_0004
17/09/22 20:33:51 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1506081922448_0004
17/09/22 20:33:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1506081922448_0004/

17/09/22 20:33:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1506081922448_0004
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I run the virtual machine using 4G memory 2 kernel, and the.Hadoop version is 2.6.4

Comment: So what is the problem

Comment: The execution of this sentence(INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1506081922448_0004) is stuck

Comment: Looks like you don't have resources to run your job. Check your NodeManagers are running and you have free cpu/memory slots. You can check it in YARN web ui: http://hostname:8088

Comment: you may alternatively check logs in command line: yarn logs -applicationId application_1506081922448_0004
Check if you see any messages as Job accepted number of times

Answer (score 0):

> 17/09/22 20:33:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job:
>   job_1506081922448_0004
>
> 1. Please go to the Resource Manager UI of YARN.
> 2. Find if any vcores and RAM is available?
> 3. If not, please wait for some resources to get free , your job will run.